# Determine if an item is selected in a listview box

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, listview, selecteditem

Using VB.net 2010 i am trying to figure out if an item was selected or not. Reason being is that if the user clicks on an item and pushes a button then everything works just fine. However, if the user selects an item and then clicks on a blank spot on the bottom of the listview and then clicks the button then it crashes.

My code is this:

```
    If (lstMaster.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox("test")
    End If
```

Any help would be great! :o)

David

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ensure that something is selected first by checking that `SelectedItems` is not empty.

```
lstMaster.SelectedItems.Count > 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, Grammarian.

Answer (score 1):

check `lstMaster.SelectedItems(0).`[`Selected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.selected.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I've understood you correctly - Try using the ListView MouseMove event and check that lstMaster.SelectedItems.Count > 0 if you want to change the Enable property of a Button based on whether a row has been selected or not within your ListView control.

Answer (score 0):

Use this checking with "If/EndIf" construction:
ListView1.Items(0).Selected = True